# Macbook pro flashing folder with '?' inside after every wake up

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, sleep

I'm not sure what's wrong. But recently my macbook pro (late 2011) crashes when I close the lid and then open it say 5 mins or more later (wake). If I do manage to get into desktop, program icons continuously bounce and never open, then i get the spinning beach ball.

Thinking it was an OS issue, I've formatted the hard drive and re installed the latest build of Yosemite.

The issue is still happening, and when it happens I have to recover the drive using the internet every time.

I'm at a loss for what to do, I fear I may have to take it to Apple to fix it, but I really don't want to as I need it for work :/

Thanks in advance!

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by wiping the hard drive and then erasing free space. I then installed OS X Yosemite using the built in network recovery. Absolutely no problems now :)

Answer (score 0):

remove all updates install only software that came with the system should be LION. install mountain lion but do not install Yosemite. or just take it back to apple. 
ide say it is hardware related. RAMM.
use as you would without any updates for at least a 2 days then update only with updates later than that . DO NOT INSTALL Yosemite.

Comment: Why would I not update it... I've had Mavericks and Yosemite with absolutely no issues since they launched. This issue has only happened this week. There's nothing wrong with the OS it's clearly the hardware if i've only just started getting this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue persists after erasing the OS, it could potentially be the flex cable that connects your hard drive to the motherboard that is defective. You can bring your computer down to an Apple Store and they can run a diagnostic.

EDIT: The repair is about $50.